# What is the proper way to handle prop-types for a component that uses object destructing and object rest...spread to collect props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { bool } from 'prop-types'

const Component = ({ active, ...rest}) => (
  // ...does things
)

Component.propTypes = {
  active: bool.isRequired,
  // -> how do i handle { ...rest } here?
  rest: object // ? works, but is it the right solution?
}
```

`Component` destructures its `props`, grabbing the `active` prop and collecting the "rest" into `rest`. Is there a way to validate `rest` using `prop-types`? Is it required? Not sure what to do.

Comment: There won't be a way to handle that through a loop without knowing all props ahead of time. You'll have to manually enter each value that you know could be a possible prop.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.ian-thomas.net/custom-proptype-validation-with-react/

Basically, prop-types does allow custom validation. You set it to

```
Component.propTypes = {
  rest: function(props, propName, componentName) { // return null if all is well }
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't know the structure of `rest` ahead of time? How would a custom validator help that.

Comment: If you don't know the structure of rest ahead of time, why do you need to put it in propTypes at all? Like you said, you can just define it as an object and leave it at that. PropTypes is just if you want to validate the props and check they're there.

Comment: `rest: PropTypes.object.isRequired` will fill your needs if you do'nt need validation but you need the property there; if it's optional, then `rest: PropTypes.object`

Answer (score 0):

Although it's late, here I'm leaving a snippet of how I do things in case I want to extend a library or same concept can be utilized when building own component

(This is in case you don't want to use typescript and stay with plain old javascript)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";

let BtnBaseProps = Object.assign(
  {
    leftIcon: "",
    rightIcon: "",
  },
  Button.prototype.props
);

/**
 *
 * @param {BtnBaseProps} props
 * @returns
 */
const BtnBase = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button {...props}>
      {props.leftIcon ? <i className={sicon + " mr-2"} /> : null}
      {props.children}
      {props.rightIcon ? <i className={eicon + " ml-2"} /> : null}
    </Button>
  );
};

BtnBase.propTypes = {
  leftIcon: PropTypes.string,
  rightIcon: PropTypes.string,
  ...(Button.propTypes && Button.propTypes),
};

export default BtnBase;
```